# sqlplus SELECT from the selected result

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am using Oracle sqlplus and am trying to use the result being selected from the codes below and select the column again from Table_1

```
SELECT * 
FROM
(
SELECT Column_Name 
FROM All_Tab_columns 
WHERE Table_Name=UPPER('Table_1')
)
INTERSECT
(
SELECT Column_Name 
FROM All_Tab_columns 
WHERE Table_Name=UPPER('Table_2')
);
```

How can I perform something like that:

```
SELECT <Columns_That_Intersected>
FROM Table_1;
```

Is it possible to store the Columns_That_Intersected in a variable/function/procedure and use it again for other select statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Just save the aggregated result of the query in a [substitution variable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqpug/using-scripts-in-SQL-Plus.html#GUID-68AC9FF2-B92A-48D1-9699-133D47F8DDC1). Something like this:

```
create table items1 as 
select rownum id, 'me '||rownum name, 1 dummy
from xmlTable ('1 to 3');
create table items2 as select id, name from items1;

set verify off
col Columns_That_Intersected new_value Columns_That_Intersected noprint 

select listagg (column_name, ',') within group (order by null) Columns_That_Intersected
from (
    select column_name
    from All_Tab_Columns 
    where Table_Name=UPPER('items1')
    intersect
    select column_name
    from All_Tab_columns 
    where Table_Name=UPPER('items2')
);

prompt Columns_That_Intersected=&Columns_That_Intersected
select &Columns_That_Intersected 
from items1;
```

Output:

```
Columns_That_Intersected=ID,NAME

        ID NAME
---------- -------------------------------------------
         1 me 1
         2 me 2
         3 me 3
```

[About col[umn] command](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqpug/COLUMN.html#GUID-643B665F-B134-4A0B-88F7-10400D6D199E)

Comment: Thanks, 0xdb. Took me quite sometime before I understood this.
Just want to confirm a few things with you. Am I right to say that the syntax behind SELECT must be a "Column Variable"? 
In other words, if I declared Columns_That_Intersected as CHAR, it will not work?

Comment: What do you mean by "the syntax behind SELECT must be a "Column Variable""? There is no special syntax for the SELECT clause. Here, "Columns_That_Intersected" is the column alias of the CHAR data type.

Comment: Sorry, I meant " the syntax **after** SELECT ". Just to clarify, so COLUMN command is part of the SELECT FROM WHERE query syntax. NEW_VALUE stores the Columns_That_Intersected into a Substitution Variable to be used in the later part of the script. Is that right?

Comment: The COLUMN command is part of the SQL*Plus. It's **not** part of the SELECT query syntax. NEW_VALUE  specifies a variable to hold a column value after execution of the query.

Answer (score 1):

Just to fetch the column names which exists in both the table table1 and table2, you can use below query:

```
SELECT Column_Name
  FROM all_tab_columns t1
 WHERE table_name = 'Table1'
   AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
                 FROM all_tab_columns t2
                WHERE table_name = 'Table2'
                  AND t2.Column_Name = t1.Column_Name);
```

Then to fetch these column values from Table1, you can use below PL/SQL construct:

```
DECLARE
v_sql_statement VARCHAR2(2000);
v_cols          VARCHAR2(2000);
BEGIN
 FOR cn IN (SELECT Column_Name
              FROM all_tab_columns t1
             WHERE table_name = 'Table1'
               AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
                             FROM all_tab_columns t2
                            WHERE table_name = 'Table2'
                              AND t2.Column_Name = t1.Column_Name))
 LOOP
    v_cols := v_cols || ', ' || cn.column_name;

 END LOOP;

 v_cols := ltrim(v_cols, ',');
 v_sql_statement := 'SELECT ' || v_cols || ' FROM Table1';
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql_statement;

END;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can, for example, work with a dynamic sql.

The result of your selects can be aggregated to a list using the listagg function

```
SELECT listagg( Column_Name,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY 1) cols
FROM
(
  SELECT Column_Name 
  FROM All_Tab_columns 
  WHERE Table_Name=UPPER('tab1')      
  INTERSECT      
  SELECT Column_Name 
  FROM All_Tab_columns 
  WHERE Table_Name=UPPER('tab2')

);
```

As result you get then eg. col1, col2, col3
with the help of this list you can then create a cursor in a plsql block and then loop through it to print out wat you want.

```
declare
  v_cols    VARCHAR2(2000);
  v_select_string varchar(2000);
  csr                SYS_REFCURSOR;
  v1            VARCHAR2(2000);
BEGIN
  SELECT listagg( Column_Name,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY 1) cols
  into v_cols
  FROM
  (
    SELECT Column_Name 
    FROM All_Tab_columns 
    WHERE Table_Name=UPPER('tab1')    
    INTERSECT    
    SELECT Column_Name 
    FROM All_Tab_columns 
    WHERE Table_Name=UPPER('tab2')  
  );

  v_select_string   := 'SELECT ' || v_cols  ||
                       ' FROM tab1';

  OPEN csr FOR v_select_string;

  LOOP
    FETCH csr INTO v1;

    EXIT WHEN csr%NOTFOUND;         

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( v1);
  END LOOP;

  CLOSE csr;
END P1;
```

Comment: statement `FETCH csr INTO v1;` will give error if there are multiple columns in `v_cols` .. to avoid this, use `FOR i IN csr` instead of `LOOP`

Comment: Hi hotfix, just want to clarify some stuff. For the command `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( v1)` , is it something like: place the VARCHAR(2) value as syntax into the script?

Comment: @FlyFlyWing `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` print the string on your screen. so you can see the value of a variable.

Comment: @hotfix i see... so the part that executed the string as the syntax is `OPEN csr FOR v_select_string;` Am I right?